# CSS - Why is this invisible margin being applied to my <a> tag css-button?

Tags: html, css, button

I was having trouble with two types of buttons.
It was a form button and a css button basically. And I was advised that the css button whould use display:inline-block;
This made the whole a href tag actually look like a button. 
But this invisible margin seems to be screwing up something. I tried separating them into separate css classes, but oddly, applying a real margin to the css button gives an additional margin as well. What's causing this?

You can easily see it here (low graphics):
www.matkalenderen.no

Basically, code looks like this:

```
      <input type="submit" value="Logg inn" class="button_blue" alt="ready to login"> 
      <a class="button_css_red" href="access.php">Glemt passord</a>
```

CSS

```
.button_red, .button_blue, .button_css_red, .button_css_blue {
    background-image:url("../img/sprite_buttons.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:inline-block;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    height:27px;
    width:98px;
}

.button_css_red, .button_css_blue {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: Your input tag is not closed. Maybe this causes problems. Close it by replacing `>` with `/>`.

Comment: Oh, that is just me not copying the copy correctly :)

Comment: Curious problem. But no, it's not the closed tag (or not any more). You can use Firebug to check the boxes, they're independent.

Comment: Yes the boxes are independent from each other. Only thing that's applied to both of them are the graphics basically. Could it have something to do with the text inside the buttons perhaps? Notice how the text of the red button is at the same height as the other one. Only the graphics are skewed.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer myself :)

Looks like I was able to fix it by applying a line-height of about 31 pixels.

Comment: Good job, liked the site by the way.

Comment: Nice job, if your question has been resolved please tick the answer box so that it stops showing up as unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that would be nice if it was not still showing up as unanswered.